# Execute a python script from sublime text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I have been learning python since last week weeks. I am using sublime text2 editor.

I have a simple file which prints some small text. How do I run this?

I have tried using ctrl+B but it only builds the file. How can I execute it?

Comment: It will execute by default. Have a `print` in your code and you will see the result at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I am facing problem to take some input from user. I have used raw_input but unable to enter any value

Comment: Interacting with the console or an application is not possible with SublimeText. Or you can keep command line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can accept user input in Sublime Text with SublimeREPL module. Install it via package control.